# Update data of two fields from another page

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables soft_group(100M data) and soft(120M data). The fields of these tables are almost identical, I need to add 2 fields call_status, call_status_code to the soft_group table and fill them with data from the soft table. I added two fields, but I can't load them correctly, for some reason the data is duplicated and exceeds 240 million (should not be more than 100 million).

My script:

```
  INSERT /*+ append enable_parallel_dml parallel(16)*/
    INTO SOFT_GROUP(CALL_STATUS,CALL_STATUS_CODE)
    SELECT --+ parallel(16)
           rs.call_status AS call_status,
           rs.call_status_code AS call_status_code
    FROM SOFT s
    WHERE s.call_id = call_id
    AND s.start_time = start_time
    AND s.phonenumber = phonenumber;
```

Also I tried with update, but it takes a lot of time:

```
UPDATE SOFT_GROUP t1
   SET (call_status, call_status_code) = (SELECT t2.call_status, t2.call_status_code
                         FROM SOFT t2
                        WHERE t1.call_id = t2.call_id
                        AND t1.start_time = t2.start_time
                        AND t1.client_id = t2.client_id)
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM OFT t2
     WHERE t1.call_id IN t2.call_id
                        AND t1.start_time = t2.start_time
                        AND t1.client_id = t2.client_id );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather say that you need to **update** current data, not insert new rows. If that's so, use `merge`.

It is unclear which column belongs to which table in code you posted so I kind of guessed it; I hope I managed to do that. If not, you should know how to uniquely match rows and which value goes into which column.

```
merge into soft_group a
using soft b
on (a.call_id         = b.call_id
    and a.start_time  = b.start_time
    and a.phonenumber = b.phonenumber
   )
when matched then update set
  a.call_status      = b.call_status,
  a.call_status_code = b.call_status_code;
```

Comment: You're welcome. Note that columns used in ON clause should be indexed. Also, updating 100 million of rows **will** take time. Perhaps you should consider not keeping the same data in two tables; alter one of them and add columns that are missing and work with just one table.

Comment: there can be different call_status for one call_id, so I think it's better to take an exact definition by start_time

Comment: @liitlefoot , how can i insert this into loop? DECLARE
dat date;
BEGIN
  dat := TO_DATE('09.06.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
  while dat <= TO_DATE('09.06.2022 16:44:51', 'dd.mm.yyyy') loopmerge into soft_group a
using soft b
on (a.call_id         = b.call_id
    and a.start_time  = b.start_time
    and a.phonenumber = b.phonenumber
   )
when matched then update set
  a.call_status      = b.call_status,
  a.call_status_code = b.call_status_code, b.start_time = dat; commit; dat:=dat+1;end loop; end;